# What is the fear of being upside down called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I have a fear of being upside down. What's the scientific name of my phobia?

I can’t even think of bungee jumping. It literally makes me overthink everything. For example, what if the rope breaks and I fall but don’t die. I know it’s not very smart thinking about this stuff but I just do it  unconsciously.

Comment: A quick search does indeed suggest that there is no such term. This might suggest that there is no such _phobia_, but I'll leave that up to the scientists.

Comment: I hope you don’t live in the southern hemisphere ;-)

Comment: Note that many would interpret your fear of bungee jumping to be acrophobia.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a phobia to me since it is perfectly rational to consider bungee jumping insane.

Comment: The "what if the bungee cord breaks" fear isn't really about being upside-down though, is it? Lots of people would never do a bungee jump for reasons unrelated to being upside-down.

Comment: _Anokatophobia_ can be coined from Greek [άνω κάτω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%89_%CE%BA%CE%AC%CF%84%CF%89) (áno káto) meaning "upside down".

Answer (score 1):

There is no authentic scientific term for this as yet.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of *invertophobia* being used for exactly what the OP describes, but none from what one would call a reliable source.

Comment: @CharlE You’re from Oxford I see, so I vote for you as a reliable source.